# Implementing Struct for Trait: cannot infer type

Tags: rust, struct, traits

Getting the following error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/client.rs:35:30
   |
35 |     println!("client: {:?}", Command::add_task("test", 10));
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: Command`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0283`.
```

---

```
pub trait Command {
    fn add_task(name: impl Into<String>, interval: u8) -> AddTask;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct AddTask {
    name: String,
    interval: u64,
}

impl Command for AddTask {
    fn add_task(name: impl Into<String>, interval: u8) -> AddTask {
        AddTask {
            name: name.into(),
            interval: 10,
        }
    }
}

println!("{:?}", Command::add_task("test", 10));
```

Comment: You're calling a trait directly. You should call this on something that *implements* the trait. In your case that's `AddTask::add_task(..)`.

Comment: The way you've organized this is a little odd, and is probably the source of the confusion. Normally you don't implement traits like this on the return types, but instead on some kind of implementer, like `ExampleCommand`.

Comment: To me, it doesn't seem like the `Command` trait needs to exist at all. You've already specialized its return type to a particular implementation, so perhaps the `add_task` should just be in an inherent `impl` for `AddTask`.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Defining methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#defining-methods), then [Traits: Defining shared behaviors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-02-traits.html). The compiler's  error message is obscure, but this code could only be reached with a grave misunderstanding of traits and method definitions.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger It does. I need to build a Vec of Commands, so I need to unify multiple different traits under the one command.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but the way `AddTask` implements `add_task` seems really bizarre. I'd expect `TestCommand` to implement `add_task` which returns `AddTask`, not a trait implementation that returns...itself?

Comment: Or is `add_task` here intended to add that task to the command? If so, why isn't `Command` just a `struct` with some kind of `CommandTask` trait you use to plug in various "tasks"?

Comment: For example the `AddTask` implementation of `add_task` doesn't even care about `AddTask` itself, it's more coincidental.